# How to hide horizontal scrollbar in right side TOC?

Tags: maven, asciidoctor

I'm using the asciidoctor-maven-plugin to generate asciidoctor.
The output contains a right side TOC.

When the links in this TOC get to large the TOC displays a horizontal scrollbar.

Can I easily disable this by adding some simple css via the asciidoctor-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the default definition in `asciidoctor.css`:

```
#toc.toc2 {
  width: 20em;
}
```

Change this to your requirements in an own copy of the css file (`my-theme.css`) and use it in the asciidoctor-maven-plugin via:

```
<configuration>
  <attributes>
    <stylesheet>my-theme.css</stylesheet>
  </attributes>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thx Torsten, when creating a stylesheet like that I loose all default styling. Should I copy some default css (where to find it?) or can I just add some css extensions in my theme?

Comment: You need to get a copy of the original file and edit that. You find it initially alongside with your html output document in the target/generated/docs folder (leaving out above configuration change) .